# Properties assigned to UIButton in ViewController.swift and segue works on Simulator but not on Device

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode10

I have an extremely bizarre problem. I created a UIButton and put it on my ViewController storyboard. I added a segue from the Button to another ViewController by pressing control and dragging. I also added an outlet to the corresponding ViewController file and added a border color and width (to the button). The segue and the button border work fine on the simulator but on a device the button border does not show up and the segue does not work.

The only thing I can think of that could be causing the problem is that a little while ago I accidentally deleted my Main.storyboard, so I dragged it from my trash back to my Xcode project. But I am pretty sure my app has worked on the device even after that incident. I wasn't sure if my viewDidLoad method was being fired (since that is where I set my border color and width for the button) so I added a print statement and found out that it was indeed being called. Take a look at the code below...

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Begin Setup Process...")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        calibrateButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        calibrateButton.layer.borderWidth = 3
    }
```

How would I get this to work on my device as well? What I am doing wrong

Comment: Have Your Tried Your Styling Code in viewWillAppear Instead of viewDidLoad ?

Comment: What difference will that make if viewDidLoad() is being called? @hussnainahmad

Comment: All of the answers are troubleshooting why my border is not showing up. But.. 1. The Border is showing on a simulator but NOT  on a device. 2. None of the answers have explained any possible reason why the SEGUE linked to the button is working on the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: 1) That happens sometimes things won't work on real devices as they works on simulators. 2 ) There are some preferences for override functions like viewWillAppear will call out first rather then viewDidLoad. as They are understandable by their names.

Comment: play with setting `clipsToBounds`, `masksToBounds` to `true`. `calibrateButton.layer.clipsToBounds = true`, `calibrateButton.layer.masksToBounds = true`

Comment: @SrikanthAdavalli I played around with those settings, (I assume when you said calibrateButton.layer.clipsToBounds that you meant calibrateButton.clipsToBounds = true). Setting those settings to true makes the button disappear entirely (while running on a physical device). I also got my hands on a different iPhone 6s running iOS 12.3.1 and I am having the same problems there. So it is definitely not a device specific issue. However when I set these settings to true and run it on the simulator the button is still visible and works fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: I have had an interesting development. I tried running my app on the iPhone 6s simulator (I was running it on the iPhone XR simulator) and the same thing that happens on my actual iPhone 6s also happens on the iPhone 6s simulator (the border doesn't show up and the segue does not work). So the problem has nothing to do with a device. It is most likely a UI problem. After making this discovery I changed my button background to red and for some reason it is not showing up. What could be causing this strange problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. The problem was that I didn't have a height constraint on my button. I am still not exactly sure why or how this issue occurred. Why couldn I see the button text but not the border? If the segue was not working there must have been a view on top of the button that was preventing it from going off. But anyway adding a height constraint solved the problem. In answering my own question I realize that the title of my question is misleading in relation to the solution of the problem. This problem, in the end had nothing to do with wether the app was running on a simulator or the device. I just assumed it was a device issue since it was working fine on my iPhone XR simulator but not my actual iPhone 6s. However the actual problem was the screen size and how my constraints adapted to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Your Border Styling Here...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code to change `layer` properties of `calibrateButton` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, i.e.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    calibrateButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    calibrateButton.layer.borderWidth = 3
}
```

Also, since you're giving `borderColor` as `white`, that might not be visible if the `calibrateButton` is placed on a *white background*. Try changing it to something else that is more visible, `red` for example.

Comment: I just tried this and it is still not showing up on the device. Do you have any other ideas why this isn't working? @PGDev

Comment: Which device and iOS version are you using?

Comment: I am using an iPhone 6s on iOS 11.1. @PGDev

Answer (score 0):

First try in `viewDidAppear()`, if it works then cut and paste it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.